# ASP.NET: OnChange on Dynamically Created Textbox inside UpdatePanel Fires Twice

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Pretty basic set-up. I'm creating a number of textboxes, all calling a function during the onchange event to update their value to the database. These boxes are dynamically created in the backend because the data changes based on specific criteria that can be changed on the page. Here's the creation of the boxes:

```
Dim t as TableRow
tC = New TableCell
Dim txtBox As New TextBox
txtBox.ID = "SampleTextBox" & counter
txtBox.Text = dt.Rows(i)(11).ToString
txtBox.ClientIDMode = UI.ClientIDMode.Static
txtBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return UpdateLabTestValue('" & txtBox.ClientID & "');")
tC.CssClass = "padBoth"
tC.Controls.Add(txtBox)
t.Cells.Add(tC)
tblResults.Rows.Add(t)
```

On the HTML side of the ball:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uplResults" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class="formContentLeft">
      <fieldset class="collapsible" style="width: 90%;">
        <legend>Results</legend>
          <div class="formContentLeft">
            <div class="formField">
              <span class="formInline">Status: </span><span class="formInput">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="dlStatus" runat="server" /></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <asp:Table ID="tblResults" runat="server" />
       <div class="centeredButtonRow">
         <asp:Button ID="btnSaveResults" runat="server" Text="Save" />
       </div>
       <asp:Label ID="errorMessage" runat="server" CssClass="errorMessage" />
      </fieldset>
     </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I enter a number into the Textbox, the event fires as expected, but it fires twice. Any thoughts?

Comment: A couple of questions: You mean the clientside `onchange` event fires twice? Where and when are you creating the TextBoxes(Page_Load? Also on Postbacks?)? Does the `counter`-variable can change during postbacks so that a TextBox gets another ID than before? What does `UpdateLabTestValue`?

Comment: Clientside onchange event. Textboxes are created on Postbacks and in Page_Load. Counter variable increments to give each textbox a unique ID. UpdateLabTestValue does nothing right now as I'm trying to fix this problem first.

Comment: Have you looked into the generated HTML and/or breakpoints set  in the javascript?

Comment: Yep. Generated HTML is simply onchange="return UpdateLabTestValue('SampleTextBox9');". Breaking on Javascript doesn't reveal anything really. I can't see why it would be posting back twice at all.

Comment: You don't have set AutoPostBack="True", so why should it postback at all `onchange` of the TextBoxes? You've mentioned that the clientside `onchange` is the problem, no you're telling that it postbacks twice.

Comment: Not posting back. It hits the client side function twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed this to an "onblur" and it works. There must be something else causing the fire for the change, although the same textbox is firing it off twice. In any case, I resolved this by switching to onblur.